# How do I convert ISO-8601 object into DateTime format in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the pandas dataframe:

```
User          Date
George      2020-06-11T19:38:01.000Z
Bob         2020-06-11T19:02:02.000Z
Ryan        2020-06-11T19:20:02.000Z
Tyler       2020-06-11T19:40:09.000Z
```

It's currently in ISO 8601 format. I was wondering how could I convert the Date column into a datetime format (Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) for remove timezone information (if necessary):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.tz_convert(None)
print (df)
     User                Date
0  George 2020-06-11 19:38:01
1     Bob 2020-06-11 19:02:02
2    Ryan 2020-06-11 19:20:02
3   Tyler 2020-06-11 19:40:09
```

Or use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: in my case, `.dt.tz_convert(None)` did not work but `.tz_localize(None)` works. thought to share